# /tmp directory clean up after python script execution

Tags: python

I am using python and invoking external utility "send-data" in my .py file as shown below,

```
cmd=['send-data', '-f', file_name]
res = subprocess.run(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, input=b'a')
```

I have no control over send-data utility and it creates file under /tmp directory with random name as shown below in the response string.

```
'a)bort, e)dit or s)end? send-data: the file remains in /tmp/pbadLWX .'
```

Wondering how can i delete the file "pbadLWX" under /tmp folder after each execution? Considering every time file name could be different?

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete it manually. It's the temporary directory, after all. Usually it gets deleted when you reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the output via [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module and then delete the file via [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove):

```
import os
import re

f_name = re.search(r'\s(/tmp/[a-zA-Z]+)\s', res.stdout.decode('ascii')).group(1)
os.remove(f_name)
```

Comment: While it may work, I find it risky - a mistake in the regex and you delete something you didn't mean  to.

Comment: @mkrieger1 This regex isn't too complicated and whatever it matches starts with `/tmp/` so in the end you're only deleting temporary files. And of course, unittests should reveal such problems in general.

Comment: This is full error message and i am getting error, b'a)bort, e)dit or s)end? send-date: the problem report remains in /tmp/pbadLWXEnu and is not sent.\n'       f_name = re.search(r'(/tmp/[a-zA-Z]+) \.$', res).group(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 173, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @Ammad This is because `subprocess.run` returns encoded output, so you need to decode in order to get a string. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for response. I got this message, AttributeError: 'CompletedProcess' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @Ammad Have you ever taken a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)? Since the returned object is a [`CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) instance you should use `res.stdout.decode('ascii')` instead.